# Searching in PDFs increases app's memory usage too much

Tags: ios, pdfkit

I noticed that when I am searching in large PDFs the app's memory usage increases because the PDFKit is doing some internal search caching. Is there any way to control this cache size? In my case the cached memory increases more than 500 MB when searching is done.

For searching within a PDF Document, I used:

`func beginFindString(_ string: String, withOptions options: NSString.CompareOptions = [])`

Comment: Is there any reason why you have to do this on the phone itself and not server side?

Comment: In my opinion, I would probably accomplish this via a web service of some kind so that the heavy lifting is done on your server and not the phone, which has limited resources as it is.

Comment: 1. how big is the PDF? Does that happen also if the PDF is just 3-5 pages? 2. When does it reduce the memory back to normal? Does it go back to its normal usage the second you search is finished? 3. FYI while 500 is a lot, as long as it goes back to what is was before then it's not a big deal, because your app won't have a big memory footprint when its in background hence it won't be relaunched again.. Although it would be bad to other apps, because your apps needs maybe 500MB of memory and it needs to kick off a few other apps

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your opinions. The requirement was to search within a PDF on the client side. In my case the PDF was about 300 pages that also contained images. 
After searching was done, the memory usage did not drop a bit until the PDFDocument was deallocated. This usually happens when the screen containing the PDFView was dismissed. I assume this is some kind of optimization done by the PDFKit that indexed the pages while searching.

I found a workaround that worked without increasing the app memory usage too much.
My solution was to instantiate a new `PDFDocument` object every `x` pages. I parsed the text for each page in range `nx ..< (n+1)x` and searched for the keyword(s). By instantiating a new object of PDFDocument every range, the previous object was released and so were the indexed pages. Additionally, the text string for each page could be cached which requires less memory than the PDFKit internal document indexing while searching. If the pages were cached, the following times the search performed almost instantly.

This solution had good performance results. It also had the advantage of knowing what is the progress of the current search. This is because you have the information of the current range and the total number of ranges required to finish searching. In addition, this solution could also be parallelized by performing the search within each range in a separate thread.

Comment: very intelligent way of tackling the issue

Comment: can you show me " how to instantiate a new PDFDocument object every x pages, 
 parsed the text for each page ", how to get several PDFDocument with a big PDFDocument

Answer (score 0):

if string.isEmpty or very little, do not call this method, just return

Comment: Regardless of the search term, the entire document is indexed. I have documents of ~1000 pages whose indexing goes up to more than 1.2GB which makes the application crash for memory issue on some devices. In addition, it does not seem possible to search by page packages and delete the indexed cache between each search

Comment: @Khorwin If I use my iPhone 5S, I also experience the phone hanging when it wants to do heavy stuff. 500page is a lot. But as long as the memory goes back down it should be good. Most of the newer generations fo iPhone 2Gb which shouldn't crash. Basically anything more than less than the half of the iPhones's RAM is considered OK by Apple's standards.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to accomplish this server-side somehow where there is a much larger capacity for caching and such than your phone can manage.